# sending mail using gmail SMTP and OAuth2.0

Tags: zend-framework, smtp, gmail

I got struck with this error for past 2 days of time. The objective is simple. I tried out sending emails using gmail smtp oauth and zend mailer for this work. I got this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '5.5.2 Cannot Decode response iv3sm786895pbc.40 - gsmtp ' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:431
>
> Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Smtp.php(265): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(250, 300)
>
> :#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail/Transport/Smtp.php(207): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->mail('saravanan1115@g...')
>
> :#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
>
> :#3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
>
> :#4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/send.php(292): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
>
> :#5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-mas in /opt/lampp/htdocs/salaikumar/handmadeimap-master/gmailoauthexample/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php on line 431

Any one help me out with this? I referred this blog to create a Xoauth.php http://piecewiseinc.blogspot.in/2013/02/send-mail-with-gmail-smtp-and-xoauth.html. I saw a same post about this in over here. But this is dint help out. [Problems sending an email to google's SMTP server (with own php script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123014/problems-sending-an-email-to-googles-smtp-server-with-own-php-script).